# INSERT result of a SELECT and other values as well

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

I want to know if this is possible without a procedure or server side calls into the database.

I am trying to insert values into a table based on a select, and other values that will be provided from the server.

The select statement will return more than one result.

I am aware of the existence of INSERT SELECT, but is there any SELECT INSERT ? or a way to insert based on the results of a select ?

thank you

Comment: Basically "a way to insert based on the results of a select " - INSERT SELECT you've mentioned, why you asking an opposite, or I'm got the question wrong?

Comment: @sllev - the tags say 'mysql'.

Comment: @Tim: thanks, I've to go sllep ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really sure what seems to be the problem.

You can do like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (columns)
SELECT
  column or column expression1,
  column or column expression2,
  …
  constant or constant expression1,
  constant or constant expression2,
  …
FROM a set of tables/joins
WHERE …
```

Not necessarily in that order (columns, then constants), no. You can mix columns with constants any way you like, just follow the order of the columns you are inserting into.

Was that what you were asking about?

Comment: thank you, I didnt think of passing my values from the server into the select.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why an

```
INSERT INTO yourtable(col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM yourothertable
```

doesn't work for you.  But you could always do a SELECT INTO #temptable to save your query in a temporary table and then you could INSERT that data or manipulate it prior to inserting.  This is just a long way around the original idea, though.

Am I misunderstanding your questions?

Comment: the problem is that the insert needs other values too, not only those form the select

Comment: @Abraham: Where these other values will come from?

Comment: they will be sent from the server, the reason I need to do everything in sql is that this is an example for a database class

Comment: Then use a temp table and union the extra data before the insert statement. Ensure that this is in one connection, as temp tables are dropped upon creating connection drop.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Use this query:

```
INSERT INTO FOO (oof, rab) SELECT (foo, bar) FROM BAR;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO targetTable (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM sourceTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'something' AS col1, 'something else' AS col2, 'yet something else' AS col3 FROM DUAL;
```